# In a delta generator, will each phase voltage always be shifted 120°?

Tags: ac, generator, three-phase, electric-machine, phase-shift

I'm confused by all the different phases and angles.

Where I live we have a delta generator (3P3W) 230 V system. I was told that the three voltage phases will always be shifted 120° from each other...

... but won't a reactive load in the household shift these? Or I'm mixing up input and output voltage?

Comment: The phase angle remains the same, that is dependent on the generator and how it is woundr. It appears you are also mixing in power factor. Spend a bit of time on power factor it should then fall into place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reactive loads connected to the service will cause a phase shift of the current in each phase with respect to that phase's voltage.  The phase relationship between voltages of the three phases will not change.

Comment: So the voltage over a load will always be in phase with the input?

Comment: By input I mean phase/line voltage at the generator. But if the wiring is causing a small phase shift of the voltage, won’t the load also cause it? I have definitely missed something here, but didn’t you also say the only thing shifting was the phase current in respect to its phase voltage? Sorry, this is difficult.

Comment: @NorwegianClassic Sorry, I hit Enter before proofreading my last comment: the voltages will be in phase at the load with respect to the source, unless we're talking about great distances (where this becomes a transmission line question, which I don't think it is).  *Currents* will shift in phase due to the wire.